# passing asynchronous event data from Javascript to Django view

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, events

My application should allow me to drag div's around a parent container and when dropped, I would have to save the new x and y position of the element via my Django BE into the database. As this drag and drop is fully asynchronous to anything happening in the Django domain, I need my javascript trigger an event in Django. And I am stuck as I don't know how to do this.

Say I use jQuery UI and do some code like below:

```
$('.person').draggable({
    containment: 'parent',
    grid : [50, 50],
    start: function(element) {
        console.log("started");

    },
    stop: function(element) {
        console.log("stopped", $(this).css("top"), $(this).css("left"), this.id);  
    }
});
```

As you see, the function call on "stop" is fully asynchronous.
I should now be able to pass x,y position plus the id of the element bak into a Django view to be saved in the database.

I don't think I can use AJAX or similar

Any solution for me?

thanks

Comment: Why do you think you can't use Ajax for this? On the contrary, that is exactly what you would do. Why can't you send an Ajax post inside the `stop` function?

Comment: Use ajax and check request.is_ajax() and get the data in request.GET or request.POST P.S. add `{% csrf_token %}` into data body otherwise you will get csrf errors

Comment: thanks a lot to both of you. I think I start to understand. I add to my stop function something like
    stop: function(element) {
        console.log("stopped", $(this).css("top"), $(this).css("left"), this.id);  

        $.ajax({
        url: '/ajax/new_coordinates/',
        data: {
          'id': this.id,
          'x': $(this).css("left"),
          'y': $(this).css("top")
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
          print("ajax success")
        }
      });
    }
then add the url, get my Python function run with request.GET.get()